# How to oppen base application from extension in iOs

Tags: objective-c, imessage, ios-extensions

I'm trying to open base application from iMessage app, which is an extension in my xcode project(added as target app). Im using`[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler::^(BOOL success) {}];`

but it doesn't work.
here is info.plist in base app

[image]

here is info.plist in imessages extension
[image]

Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found the right answer. I was opening base app from another viewController using the extensionContext property of MSMessagesAppViewController, but that viewController was presenting on top of the rootVC. It happens that rootVC opens urls very well, but any other doesn't. So i simply request my rootVC to open url using extensionContext.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But now you will get compiler error. To fix the compiler error, do this. Set `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` to `NO` in your extension's build settings.

[image]

Comment: Hi, i did as you said and it works, but is this normal ? I mean it's extenssion, how it can use UIApplication class ? Also, can it cause problems in release build ?

Comment: I don't think there will be any issues.